# Custom Lookup iteration in Multiple rows

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-cli

I have created a custom lookup for Name and Related fields for Task and Event objects. And added Multiple rows to enter the records to save but the custom Lookup component is not Iterating while deleting the records in a row.

Is custom Lookup component will Iterate in Multiple rows.

Comment: please update your question with a code sample showing what you are trying to do and a discussion of any blogs you have read in trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.